# How can refresh multiple iframes using the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How can refresh multiple iframes using the same ID.
Code Sample:

```
<iframe id="x123"></iframe>
<iframe id="x123"></iframe>
<iframe id="x123"></iframe>
```

I test

```
document.getElementById('x123').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

or

```
parent.document.getElementById('x123').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

The first one is just on the other it does not refresh.

Thanks :)

Comment: Because id stands for identity. So, identity is always unique.

Comment: You probably meant same class, not id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` stands for identity, which technically is always unique. You probably meant "same class", not "same id".

Change `id` attribute to `class`.

```
<iframe class="x123"></iframe>
<iframe class="x123"></iframe>
<iframe class="x123"></iframe>
```

Access the elements using jquery:

```
$('.x123')
```

Look for equivalent jquery code for `contentWindow.location.reload()`.

Comment: Thank you so mush :)
I add code :
$('.x123').each(function() {
   this.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
});